# Dynamo DB - Update / Delete

Tags: javascript, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

How to do I do when I want to remove one Json object from the below example?

```
{ Name : "abc",
  EMail : "abc@gmail.com"
  Fruits : [{
    Name : "name",
    family: "Z"
},
{
    Name : "name",
    family: "A"
},
{
    Name : "name",
    family: "B"
},
{
    Name : "name",
    family: "C"
}
]
}
```

From the above example if I wanted to remove `{ Name : "name", family: "C" }`. I know that family = C and it is unique.

How do I achieve this in Aws DynamoDB using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = { 
"Name" : "abc",
  "EMail" : "abc@gmail.com",
  "Fruits" : [{
    "Name" : "name",
    "family": "Z"
},
{
    "Name" : "name",
    "family": "A"
},
{
    "Name" : "name",
    "family": "B"
},
{
    "Name" : "name",
    "family": "C"
}
]
}
data.Fruits = data.Fruits.filter(val => ((val.Name == "name" && val.family != "C") ||  (val.Name != "name" && val.family == "C")));
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thanks! But This helps in displaying but not removing directly in DB